# C - when condition weird issue

Tags: c, data-structures, while-loop, linked-list

so I was trying to implement a function to detect a cycle in a linked list, and basically, I was struggling until I realized I just had to switch 2 conditions.

This code doesn't work, it produces a SIGSEV error:

```
bool has_cycle(SinglyLinkedListNode* head) {

    struct SinglyLinkedListNode *slow = head;
    struct SinglyLinkedListNode *fast = head;
    
    while(slow && fast->next && fast)
    {
        fast = fast->next->next;
        slow = slow->next;
        
        if(fast == slow)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;

}
```

but when I switch `while(slow && fast->next && fast)` for `while(slow && fast && fast->next)` it works. Why?

Comment: `while(slow && fast && fast->next)` Google for "short circuit evaluation"

Answer (score 3):

Imagine if `fast` is `NULL`. Trying to evaluate `fast->next` will cause your code to crash. So you need to check if `fast` is `NULL` first.

Since those three conditions are changed by an AND, as soon as one of them is `false`, the entire result is known to be `false`. So evaluation stops and a `NULL` is never dereferenced. This is called "short circuit evaluation".

A common pattern in C and C++ is something like `if (foo && (foo->bar == baz))` for just this reason.

Answer (score 0):

The `fast` in your condition is testing that `fast` is not null, if its determined to be not null, the `fast->next` condition is tested. If you test `fast->next` first, `fast` has the possibility of being null which is why you get the seg fault.